# A regular space is Lindelof iff ...

Tags: general-topology, lindelof-spaces

This question is part of my Topology assignment and I am stuck on it. So, I am asking for guidance here.

> Prove that a regular $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is Lindelöf iff each open cover $\mathcal{O}$ has a countable subset $\mathcal{O}'=\{U_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ such that $\{\overline{U_n} \mid U_n \in \mathcal{O}'\}$ covers $X$.

I have proved it lindelöf assuming the given condition but I am unable to think how should I proceed converse because the set  of $\overline{U_n}$ covering $X$ are not are not open and I am unable to think how should I find such subcover.

Please guide.

Comment: Has a countable collection? You mean a countable subset?

Comment: If the $U_n$ (which *are* open) cover $X$ so do their closures, obviously. The existence of the $U_n$ is immediate. The other direction is more subtle and needs the regularity. You claim to have proved this? Add it into the question to show effort.